# Get all ul elements in between two h3 tags

Tags: xpath, beautifulsoup, ixmldomelement

Following is how the element looks like on the page:

[image]

Programs and Courses are *h3* tags. I want all the ul tags in *between* Programs and Courses. Following XPath gives me all the ul comes after Programs:

```
"//h3[.='Programs']/following::ul"
```

How do I filter it to have the only *ul* which comes in between Courses and Program.

Screenshot Source: https://catalog.fullerton.edu/preview_entity.php?catoid=16&ent_oid=1837&returnto=1920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required `ul` nodes:

```
//h3[.='Programs']/following-sibling::ul[following-sibling::h3[.='Courses']]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works fine. How did it exclude the ul after Courses?

Comment: `[following-sibling::h3[.='Courses']]` predicate means fetch nodes followed by `h3` with text `'Courses'`. That's why all following `ul` nodes are ignored. You can use `following` as well but `following-sibling` is more suitable in this case as nodes are children of the same parent